# PHP Creating 3 Thumbnail Images of different Sizes from an uploaded image

Tags: php, php-gd

I'm trying to create 3 Thumbnail Images of different sizes, from the same uploaded Image. Presently, I use the code below to create 1 thumbnail that's 150px wide.

Is there an easy way to do this instead of repeating the same code thrice for each thumbnail I need?

I'm trying to create thumbnails in 3 sizes: 750px wide, 150px wide and 70px wide.

Here's the code I use to do the Thumbnail that's 150Px wide.

Does PHP have a function to do such a thing, or is repeating the code below for each size I need my only option.

```
if(file_exists($thisImage)) {

    $imageName = $thisImage;
    $imageInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $imageType = finfo_file($imageInfo, $imageName);
    finfo_close($imageInfo);


    if($imageType == 'image/pjeg' || $imageType == 'image/jpeg' || $imageType == 'image/jpg') {
        $imgSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($thisImage);
    } elseif ($imageType == 'image/png') {
        $imgSource = imagecreatefrompng($thisImage);
    } elseif ($imageType == 'image/gif') {
        $imgSource = imagecreatefromgif($thisImage);
    } else {
        $imgSource = false;
        return false;
    }

    if($imgSource) {
        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($thisImage);

        $thumbImageWidth = 150;
        $thumbImageHeight = ($height/$width)*$thumbImageWidth;
        $tempThumbImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight);

        if(!imagecopyresampled($tempThumbImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight,$width,$height)) return false;

        $thumbImageTarget = $thisPath.$thisName;

        if(!imagejpeg($tempThumbImage,$thumbImageTarget,100)) return false;

        if(!imagedestroy($imgSource)) return false;

        if(!imagedestroy($tempThumbImage)) return false;

        if(!unlink($thisImage)) return false;

        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can try the imagemagick library.. http://www.imagemagick.org/..

Answer (score 0):

PHP dont have that function. But you can create a function named `resize($width, $heigh)` and put your resize part in.

Answer (score 0):

zairwolf's answer is basically correct, although not thorough.

You need to create a [user defined function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

```
resize($thisImage, 70, $thisPath.$thisName."-thumb1.jpg");
resize($thisImage, 150, $thisPath.$thisName."-thumb2.jpg");
resize($thisImage, 750, $thisPath.$thisName."-thumb3.jpg");

function resize($imageName, $thumbImageWidth, $thumbImageTarget)
{
    if(file_exists($imageName)) {

        $imageInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $imageType = finfo_file($imageInfo, $imageName);
        finfo_close($imageInfo);


        if($imageType == 'image/pjeg' || $imageType == 'image/jpeg' || $imageType == 'image/jpg') {
            $imgSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageName);
        } elseif ($imageType == 'image/png') {
            $imgSource = imagecreatefrompng($imageName);
        } elseif ($imageType == 'image/gif') {
            $imgSource = imagecreatefromgif($imageName);
        } else {
            $imgSource = false;
            return false;
        }

        if($imgSource) {
            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($imageName);

            $thumbImageHeight = ($height/$width)*$thumbImageWidth;
            $tempThumbImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight);

            if(!imagecopyresampled($tempThumbImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight,$width,$height)) return false;


            if(!imagejpeg($tempThumbImage,$thumbImageTarget,100)) return false;

            if(!imagedestroy($imgSource)) return false;

            if(!imagedestroy($tempThumbImage)) return false;

            if(!unlink($imageName)) return false;

            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```